# DataTables editable (where to put the editable_ajax.php file)

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to edit my tables content by following this example [DataTables example](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html)

In my twig page I've added this script at the end:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    oTable.$('td').editable( 'editable_ajax.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "auto",
        "width": "auto"
    } );
} );
```

the file `editable_ajax.php` is in the folder where my twig page is. 
When I try to edit a cell I see with the debugging tool that the 'editable_ajax.php' file is not found, Can someone tell me where I should place it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but you seem to not have a good grasp of how templating and Symfony in general work. You're mixing very different things (PHP code, twig templates, Javascript code).

So, first read the [Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html). I would also suggest reading up on Javascript.

Some mistakes:

- PHP files should never be in the "views" folder (aka. with twig files)
- Javascript runs on the *client side* so you need to think about URLs when calling server-side code (aka. php code) NOT filesystem paths.
- Javascript (jQuery is just a library) should not be in a twig file, but it's own *.js file and linked with a `<script>` html tag.